# TSQL distinct list, but with extra data if a single original item

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

*Ideally I'd like SQL2008 compliant answers, due to customer constraints*

I need a distinct list of items, but with a column that returns a specific piece of data **if** the original data only had a single item in the first place...

Example data...

```
Id   Code
1    A
2    A
3    B
```

In the above example data I want to return a distinct list of `Code`, but if only a single instance of that code exists I want the `Id` to be returned (otherwise `null`)

Expected output...

```
Code  Id
A     null
B     3
```

I've got the following, but it feels like there should be an easier way of doing it, maybe using `GROUP BY`...

```
; WITH Data AS (
    SELECT Code, Id ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT D1.Code, CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data D2 WHERE D2.Code = D1.Code) WHEN 1 THEN D1.Id ELSE NULL END
FROM Data D1
WHERE D1.RowNum = 1
```

Can this be done in a better way?

Comment: Obligatory note that SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for almost 3 years; it is long past time you sorted your upgrade path.

Comment: @larnu - talk to my customer

Comment: I can't, @freefaller , but you can.

Comment: Your statement for me to talk to your customer *wasn't* "silly"? I don't know who you are, or who your customer is; the sensible answer to such a silly request is to tell you I can't, @Freefaller. If you mean that the statement that SQL Server 2008 is completely unsupported is silly, it's not. SQL Server 2008 has not had *any* updates in almost 3 years, and most certainly has known security vulnerabilities that will not be patched; that isn't silly it's a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation comes to mind here:

```sql
SELECT Code, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MAX(Id) END AS Id
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Code;
```

Comment: Argh, so simple! Thanks @Tim